# Salvar em linha única no DB, o resultado da variável PHP (WHILE/LOOP) de uma Query MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, loop, variáveis, while

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Ao realizar uma query, o resultado do while é composto por mais de um valor, exemplo:

```
   $query_sku = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT t.column_name
        FROM skus AS s
            INNER JOIN table AS t ON t.column_id = s.column_id
                WHERE s.id_sku = '{$id_sku}'");
WHILE($reg = mysqli_fetch_object($query_sku )){
  $variable = $reg->column_name;
echo "<br/">;
}
```

O resultado dessa query/while é:

```
BATERIA  
PARA
CÂMERA
CANON
PowerShot ELPH 330 HS
```

E caso eu mande salvar no Banco de Dados, ele salvará um retorno por linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando na verdade eu quero que ele retorne dessa maneira:

```
BATERIA PARA CÂMERA CANON PowerShot ELPH 330 HS
```

E salve no Banco de Dados em apenas uma linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se alterar o seu código para o seguinte, resolve o problema?

```
while($reg = mysqli_fetch_object($query_sku ))
    $variable .= " ".$reg->column_name;
```

Na variável `$variable` fica a concatenação de todos os valores da consulta, onde depois basta inserir esse valor na base de dados.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @João Martins, o problema é que quando eu faço isso, ele me retorno várias vezes a resposta:

 PowerShot ELPH 330 HS BATTERY (RECHARGEABLE)PowerShot ELPH 330 HS BATTERY (RECHARGEABLE) CAMERAPowerShot ELPH 330 HS BATTERY (RECHARGEABLE) CAMERA CANON

Ele concatena várias vezes, enquanto não acaba o loop

Comment: A variável não fica com esses valores todos, apenas o último. Se fizer um `echo $variable` depois do ciclo `WHILE` pode confirmar que o valor está correto.

Comment: Então @RogériodeSáJr., conseguiu resolver o problema?